# How to compute the variable mortality based on "grouped counts"?

Tags: r, dplyr, count

I've got one big dataframe called `df_incl_countries_with_outliers` with over 6000 cases and 100 variables. For simplicity, consider two variables: `Country` and `death_rate`. Every case is a person from a certain country that did or did not die (`death_rate` is dichotomous). I can get the counts of how many people died per country by using this code:

```
df_incl_countries_with_outliers %>% count(Country, death_rate)
```

The thing is though, that I want to calculate a new variable `mortality` which is calculated by all deaths of a certain country, divided by the sum of all cases of said country(minus the missing values, of course). Something like:

```
count(deaths_of_country_A/(deaths_of_country_A + alive_of_country_A))
```

and this of course for every country.

Why do I want to do this? Because I want to make a boxplot of the new variable `mortality` so that we know if certain countries are outliers.

I assume it has something to do with the `dplyr::mutate` function to create the variable and perhaps something with the `dplyr::group_by` to group by country, together with `count()` but I'm afraid that's as far as my knowledge goes. Every attempt at solving this problem of mine is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `df_incl_countries_with_outliers |> summarize(mortality_rate = mean(death_rate), .by = "Country")`? Or swap in `mutate` if you want each country's rate shown with every observation in the original data.

Comment: ^ Note, the `.by` parameter was added to many dplyr functions with v1.1.0. For prior versions, you would use `group_by(GROUPING_VAR[s]) %>% [mutate or summarize] %>% ungroup()` to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @JonSpring So, I tried this line:  `df_incl_countries_with_outliers %>% summarize(mortality_rate = mean(ICU_mortality), .by = "Country", na.rm= TRUE)`, but this gives me the error "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA". Something to do with the fact that `death_rate` is a 0/1 input (alive/dead)? I'm not sure why I would have to use the `mean` to calculate mortality, described in the post?

FYI, `dplyr` is v1.1.0.

Comment: It sounds like you might have some NAs in your "dichotomous" variable, I suspect using `mean(death_date, na.rm = TRUE)` would fix it, being equivalent to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! This is the code:

```
df_incl_countries_with_outliers <- df_incl_countries_with_outliers %>%
     group_by(Country) %>%
     mutate(
         Mortality = sum(death_rate == "Dead", na.rm = TRUE) / sum(!is.na(death_rate))
     )
```

First we group by the different countries. So when I say "all" in the following sentences, that hits on "all those in the same country". `Mutate` makes a new variable in the dataframe. The new variable is called Mortality which is equal to the sum of all the dead people (where missing values are not counted in the result) divided by the sum of all the cases (again, missing values omitted).

Comment: good on you for answering your own question! :-) a couple of things: 1. you forgot to `ungroup()` (good practice- you wouldn't believe the number of questions we get here where the problem comes back to the OP forgetting they had grouped their dataframe!), 2. you called it `Mutate` in your answer, when it is `mutate` (capitalisation matters for functions!) Otherwise great work :-)